# How to fix images not loading in phaser.js

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

Whenever I try to load images into phaser they always appear as a green box on my screen?

I've not only tried the root file path like normal, but also every file path imaginable, but it still never works?

[image]

Comment: Could you please post code instead of a screenshot? Also, if you could create a minimal example on JS Fiddle, it would help us find the problem.

Comment: // Setting the game up
const config = {
 width: 700,
 height: 700,
 type: Phaser.AUTO,
 scene: {
  preload,
  create,
  update,
 },
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);

// Global variables
const gameState = {};

// Assets
function preload() {
 this.load.image('ship', 'assets/images/Ship.PNG');
}

// Adding assets into the game
function create() {
 this.add.sprite(50, 50, 'ship');
}

// Updating loop
function update() {

}

Comment: Please update your question with the formatted code. Take a little time to read up and learn how to make a good question on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I had my 'uBlock' extension in firefox blocking my images so whitelisting solved it for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've already set up a web server.. Did you look at developer tools and check if there are any errors? On Google Chrome, right click your web page and hit inspect. Navigate to the Consoles Tab and look for errors. Be sure to also Log XMLHttpRequests, as these will indicate when the request for said image has been fulfilled (just click the Log XMLHttpRequests checkbox).

Did any of the above solutions work for you? For me, I've used a Simple HTTP Server with Python. I was referencing my images correctly and had my web server hosted correctly. When using developer tools, there were no error messages.. I was banging my head against the wall for hours. The Phaser API was not able to tell what the local directory (http://192.168.0.2:8080/) was from the webpage from some reason.

I fixed my issue by using the following path for my images:

```
'http://192.168.0.2:8080/assets/sky.png'
```

where 192.168.0.2 was my local IP address hosting the server & 8080 was the port I was using for communications

Alternative to adding that lengthy file path for each of your images, you can call the `this.load.setBaseURL('http://192.168.0.2:8080')` function in combination with what you already have.

For example, see the following code:

```
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 200 }
        }
    },
    scene: {
        
        preload: preload,
        create: create
    }
};
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload ()
{
    console.log('preload');
    this.load.setBaseURL('http://192.168.0.2:8080');
    this.load.image('bombP','bowmb.png');
    this.load.image('einMary','/bowmb.png');
}

function create ()
{
    console.log('create');
    this.add.image(126, 119, 'bombP');
    this.add.image(222,269,'einMary');
    //var s = game.add.sprite(80,0,'einMary');
    //s.rotation=0.219;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I should start by checking those two points below :

- Check if the image has the right path to the file
- Check if the 'key' you are using is the right one